# Считывать папки(файлы) по очереди в данной директории

Tags: c++

Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой: мне надо считать все файлы по очереди из директории, и, если этот файл оказался папкой, то надо открыть txt в этой папке с названием name. Пробывал несколько фрагментов кода из интернета, ничего не работает. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот где то так

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
 
int main()
{
    const std::filesystem::path etc{"your-dir"};
    
    for(auto const& dir_entry: std::filesystem::directory_iterator{etc}) {
        if (std::filesystem::is_directory(dir_entry)) {
            std::cout << dir_entry << '\n';
            auto fn = dir_entry.path() / std::string("name.txt");
            if (std::filesystem::exists(fn)) {
                std::cout << fn << "is is_exists\n";
                // добавьте свой код открытия здесь
            }
        }
    }
}
```

если что, нужен с++17 и старше.